# Is there a faster way to avoid the for loop in K cross validation in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a code for implementing the K fold cross validation in R:

```
set.seed(123)
y = rnorm(100,0,1)
x1 = rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 = rnorm(100,0,1)
x3 = rnorm(100,0,1)
x4 = rnorm(100,0,1)
x5 = rnorm(100,0,1)
data = data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);head(data)

# create k = 10 fold cross validation
folds = cut(seq(1,nrow(data)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)


# perform the cv 
for(i in 1:10){
  fold        = which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData    = data[fold, ]
  trainData   = data[-fold, ]
}
```

Is there a faster way for R to implement this k-fold cv and avoid the for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test_data` can be more efficiently divided into a list as

```
split(data, folds)

#or better
split(data, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(data))/10))
$`1`
             y          x1          x2         x3          x4          x5
1  -0.56047565 -0.71040656  2.19881035 -0.7152422 -0.07355602 -0.60189285
2  -0.23017749  0.25688371  1.31241298 -0.7526890 -1.16865142 -0.99369859
3   1.55870831 -0.24669188 -0.26514506 -0.9385387 -0.63474826  1.02678506
4   0.07050839 -0.34754260  0.54319406 -1.0525133 -0.02884155  0.75106130
5   0.12928774 -0.95161857 -0.41433995 -0.4371595  0.67069597 -1.50916654
6   1.71506499 -0.04502772 -0.47624689  0.3311792 -1.65054654 -0.09514745
7   0.46091621 -0.78490447 -0.78860284 -2.0142105 -0.34975424 -0.89594782
8  -1.26506123 -1.66794194 -0.59461727  0.2119804  0.75640644 -2.07075107
9  -0.68685285 -0.38022652  1.65090747  1.2366750 -0.53880916  0.15012013
10 -0.44566197  0.91899661 -0.05402813  2.0375740  0.22729192 -0.07921171

$`2`
            y          x1         x2         x3          x4          x5
11  1.2240818 -0.57534696  0.1192452  1.3011760  0.49222857 -0.09736927
12  0.3598138  0.60796432  0.2436874  0.7567748  0.26783502  0.21615254
13  0.4007715 -1.61788271  1.2324759 -1.7267304  0.65325768  0.88246516
14  0.1106827 -0.05556197 -0.5160638 -0.6015067 -0.12270866  0.20559750
15 -0.5558411  0.51940720 -0.9925072 -0.3520465 -0.41367651 -0.61643584
16  1.7869131  0.30115336  1.6756969  0.7035239 -2.64314895 -0.73479925
17  0.4978505  0.10567619 -0.4411632 -0.1056713 -0.09294102 -0.13180279
18 -1.9666172 -0.64070601 -0.7230660 -1.2586486  0.43028470  0.31001699
19  0.7013559 -0.84970435 -1.2362731  1.6844357  0.53539884 -1.03968035
20 -0.4727914 -1.02412879 -1.2847157  0.9113913 -0.55527835 -0.18430887

$`3`
            y          x1          x2          x3          x4         x5
21 -1.0678237  0.11764660 -0.57397348  0.23743027  1.77950291  0.9672673
22 -0.2179749 -0.94747461  0.61798582  1.21810861  0.28642442 -0.1082801
23 -1.0260044 -0.49055744  1.10984814 -1.33877429  0.12631586 -0.6984207
24 -0.7288912 -0.25609219  0.70758835  0.66082030  1.27226678 -0.2759452
25 -0.6250393  1.84386201 -0.36365730 -0.52291238 -0.71846622  1.1146485
26 -1.6866933 -0.65194990  0.05974994  0.68374552 -0.45033862  0.5500440
27  0.8377870  0.23538657 -0.70459646 -0.06082195  2.39745248  1.2366758
28  0.1533731  0.07796085 -0.71721816  0.63296071  0.01112919  0.1390979
29 -1.1381369 -0.96185663  0.88465050  1.33551762  1.63356842  0.4102751
30  1.2538149 -0.07130809 -1.01559258  0.00729009 -1.43850664 -0.5584569

$`4`
             y          x1          x2         x3          x4         x5
31  0.42646422  1.44455086  1.95529397  1.0175586 -0.19051680  0.6053707
32 -0.29507148  0.45150405 -0.09031959 -1.1884340  0.37842390 -0.5063335
33  0.89512566  0.04123292  0.21453883 -0.7216044  0.30003855 -1.4205655
34  0.87813349 -0.42249683 -0.73852770  1.5192177 -1.00563626  0.1279930
35  0.82158108 -2.05324722 -0.57438869  0.3773880  0.01925927  1.9458512
36  0.68864025  1.13133721 -1.31701613 -2.0522228 -1.07742065  0.8009143
37  0.55391765 -1.46064007 -0.18292539 -1.3640375  0.71270333  1.1652534
38 -0.06191171  0.73994751  0.41898240 -0.2007810  1.08477509  0.3588557
39 -0.30596266  1.90910357  0.32430434  0.8657794 -2.22498770 -0.6085572
40 -0.38047100 -1.44389316 -0.78153649 -0.1018833  1.23569346 -0.2022409

$`5`
             y         x1         x2          x3         x4         x5
41 -0.69470698  0.7017843 -0.7886220  0.62418747 -1.2410445 -0.2732481
42 -0.20791728 -0.2621975 -0.5021987  0.95900538  0.4547693 -0.4686998
43 -1.26539635 -1.5721442  1.4960607  1.67105483  0.6599026  0.7041673
44  2.16895597 -1.5146677 -1.1373036  0.05601673 -0.1998898 -1.1973635
45  1.20796200 -1.6015362 -0.1790516 -0.05198191 -0.6451140  0.8663661
46 -1.12310858 -0.5309065  1.9023618 -1.75323736  0.1653210  0.8641525
47 -0.40288484 -1.4617556 -0.1009749  0.09932759  0.4388187 -1.1986224
48 -0.46665535  0.6879168 -1.3598407 -0.57185006  0.8833028  0.6394920
49  0.77996512  2.1001089 -0.6647694 -0.97400958 -2.0523370  2.4302267
50 -0.08336907 -1.2870305  0.4854600 -0.17990623 -1.6363793 -0.5572155

$`6`
             y         x1          x2          x3         x4          x5
51  0.25331851  0.7877388 -0.37560287  1.01494317  1.4304023  0.84490424
52 -0.02854676  0.7690422 -0.56187636 -1.99274849  1.0466288 -0.78220185
53 -0.04287046  0.3322026 -0.34391723 -0.42727929  0.4352889  1.11071142
54  1.36860228 -1.0083766  0.09049665  0.11663728  0.7151784  0.24982472
55 -0.22577099 -0.1194526  1.59850877 -0.89320757  0.9171749  1.65191539
56  1.51647060 -0.2803953 -0.08856511  0.33390294 -2.6609228 -1.45897073
57 -1.54875280  0.5629895  1.08079950  0.41142992  1.1102771 -0.05129789
58  0.58461375 -0.3724388  0.63075412 -0.03303616 -0.4849876 -0.52692518
59  0.12385424  0.9769734 -0.11363990 -2.46589819  0.2306168 -0.19726487
60  0.21594157 -0.3745809 -1.53290200  2.57145815 -0.2951578 -0.62957874

$`7`
             y         x1          x2         x3          x4         x5
61  0.37963948  1.0527115 -0.52111732 -0.2052993  0.87196495 -0.8338436
62 -0.50232345 -1.0491770 -0.48987045  0.6511933 -0.34847245  0.5787224
63 -0.33320738 -1.2601552  0.04715443  0.2737665  0.51850377 -1.0875807
64 -1.01857538  3.2410399  1.30019868  1.0246732 -0.39068498  1.4840309
65 -1.07179123 -0.4168576  2.29307897  0.8176594 -1.09278721 -1.1862066
66  0.30352864  0.2982276  1.54758106 -0.2097932  1.21001051  0.1010792
67  0.44820978  0.6365697 -0.13315096  0.3781678  0.74090001  0.5329893
68  0.05300423 -0.4837806 -1.75652740 -0.9454088  1.72426224  0.5867353
69  0.92226747  0.5168620 -0.38877986  0.8569230  0.06515393 -0.3017467
70  2.05008469  0.3689645  0.08920722 -0.4610383  1.12500275  0.0795020

$`8`
            y          x1          x2          x3         x4          x5
71 -0.4910312 -0.21538051  0.84501300  2.41677335  1.9754191  0.96126415
72 -2.3091689  0.06529303  0.96252797 -1.65104890 -0.2814821 -1.45646592
73  1.0057385 -0.03406725  0.68430943 -0.46398724 -1.3229511 -0.78173971
74 -0.7092008  2.12845190 -1.39527435  0.82537986 -0.2393516  0.32040231
75 -0.6880086 -0.74133610  0.84964305  0.51013255 -0.2140412 -0.44478198
76  1.0255714 -1.09599627 -0.44655722 -0.58948104  0.1516805  1.37000399
77 -0.2847730  0.03778840  0.17480270 -0.99678074  1.7123050  0.67325386
78 -1.2207177  0.31048075  0.07455118  0.14447570 -0.3261439  0.07216675
79  0.1813035  0.43652348  0.42816676 -0.01430741  0.3730047 -1.50775732
80 -0.1388914 -0.45836533  0.02467498 -1.79028124 -0.2276841  0.02610023

$`9`
              y          x1         x2          x3          x4         x5
81  0.005764186 -1.06332613 -1.6674751  0.03455107  0.02045071 -0.3164159
82  0.385280401  1.26318518  0.7364960  0.19023032  0.31405766 -0.1023465
83 -0.370660032 -0.34965039  0.3860266  0.17472640  1.32821470 -1.1815592
84  0.644376549 -0.86551286 -0.2656516 -1.05501704  0.12131838  0.4986580
85 -0.220486562 -0.23627957  0.1181445  0.47613328  0.71284232 -1.0389564
86  0.331781964 -0.19717589  0.1340386  1.37857014  0.77886003 -0.2262220
87  1.096839013  1.10992029  0.2210195  0.45623640  0.91477327  0.3814258
88  0.435181491  0.08473729  1.6408462 -1.13558847 -0.57439455 -0.7835158
89 -0.325931586  0.75405379 -0.2190504 -0.43564547  1.62688121  0.5829914
90  1.148807618 -0.49929202  0.1680654  0.34610362 -0.38095674 -1.3165104

$`10`
             y          x1          x2         x3         x4         x5
91   0.9935039  0.21444531  1.16838387 -0.6470456 -0.1057842 -2.8097747
92   0.5483970 -0.32468591  1.05418102 -2.1576463  1.4040503  0.4649680
93   0.2387317  0.09458353  1.14526311  0.8842508  1.2940839  0.8405398
94  -0.6279061 -0.89536336 -0.57746800 -0.8294776 -1.0899919 -0.2858454
95   1.3606524 -1.31080153  2.00248273 -0.5735603 -0.8730710  0.5041263
96  -0.6002596  1.99721338  0.06670087  1.5039006 -1.3580791 -1.1559165
97   2.1873330  0.60070882  1.86685184 -0.7741449  0.1818472 -0.1271486
98   1.5326106 -1.25127136 -1.35090269  0.8457315  0.1648409 -1.9415184
99  -0.2357004 -0.61116592  0.02098359 -1.2606829  0.3641147  1.1811809
100 -1.0264209 -1.18548008  1.24991457 -0.3545424  0.5521577  1.8599109
```

Now your `train_data` can be also created as a list by using `purrr::map` and `anti_join` as

```
map(split(data, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(data))/10)), ~ anti_join(data, .x))
```

Its baseR equivalent should be

```
Map(function(x) setdiff(data, x), split(data1, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(data))/10)))
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. You may also consider upvote it. You may upvote multiple answers per question simultaneously